# Cannot access variable before initialization error when variable is initialized in another file

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, nodemon, ts-node

I have something like this:

photo.ts

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from "typeorm"
import { User } from "./User"

@Entity()
export class Photo {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    url: string

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.photos)
    user: User
}
```

user.ts

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm"
import { Photo } from "./Photo"

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @OneToMany(() => Photo, (photo) => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[]
}
```

Am running using `nodemon` and i have `ts-node` installed, but am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'User' before initialization
    at file:///path/to/project/src/database/entities/photo.ts:14:9
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

This error beats me as I don't even know where to start because, frankly, I have never encountered the error before, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Versions:

```
node: v18.17.1
ts-node: v10.9.1
nodemon: v3.0.1
typescript: v5.2.2
```

Comment: I don't have a (specific) solution for you, but the problem is that your two modules have a cyclic relationship and they both try to use the other's exported member during the initial module execution (thanks to the decorators). So one or the other has to be run first (`photo.ts` in your example) and when it tries to use `User`, that exported member hasn't been initialized yet because `user.ts` hasn't been executed yet. The general solution is to avoid that kind of cycle where each module tries to use the exported member from the other during the *initial* execution. But I don't know how...

Comment: ...you'd do that with the decorators above. In general, you'll have to delay the initialization of one of those classes until the other is ready. I can think of a hacky way to do that, but you'd have to pick whether to do it to `User` or `Photo` and that choice depends on how those are used by other modules.

Comment: To be clear: It's fine for modules to have cyclic relationships with each other, ESM is designed to handle that. The problem is when the top-level code in each module relies on the top-level code of the other module having already been run. In a non-cyclic relationship, the JavaScript engine can execute the modules in an appropriate order, but in a cyclic relationship it's a Catch-22.

Comment: Some information about "circular relationships" on the TypeORM website here: https://typeorm.io/#relations-in-esm-projects It says to use the `Relation` type to avoid this. Not clear to me how that helps, but I've never used TypeORM and not gotten into it in any depth, so...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it actually works, you can put in answers so i accept it, thanks alot

Comment: @​lulliezy - Hey, that's great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your two modules have a cyclic relationship and they both try to use the other's exported member during the initial module execution. So one or the other has to be run first (`photo.ts` in your example) and when it tries to use `User`, that exported member hasn't been initialized yet because `user.ts` hasn't been executed yet. I have to admit I'm slightly surprised you're getting this as a runtime error because the only place I see them being used in a cycle at the *top level* of the module code is in the types being applied to `user` and `photos`. Perhaps it has something to do with what the decorators are doing, or to the fact that `User` and `Photo` are both types *and* values (constructor functions).

The TypeORM website talks about "circular relationships" [here](https://typeorm.io/#relations-in-esm-projects). It says to use the `Relation` type to avoid this (so `user: Relation<User>` rather than `user: User`, and `photos: Relation<Photo[]>` rather than `photos: Photo[]`). Apparently this prevents the cycle from arising.